# How to remove default magento header from my custom tab - Adminhtml

Tags: module, adminhtml, header, tabs, magento1.9.2.3

I have created two tabs on my own module.

when i try to add content it shows with header, i want to remove this header.

hope anyone suggest some ideas

here i have attached screenshot.

[image]

in my Tabs.php i have this function

```
  protected function _beforeToHtml() {

    $this->addTab('update_bulkpriceupdate', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('bulkpriceupdate')->__('Bulk Price Update'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('bulkpriceupdate')->__('Bulk Price Update'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bulkpriceupdate/adminhtml_form')->toHtml(),
        'active'    => true
    ));

    $this->addTab('select_bulkupdateprice', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('bulkpriceupdate')->__('Select Products to Update Price'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('bulkpriceupdate')->__('Select Products to Update Price'),
        //'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bulkpriceupdate/adminhtml_select_grid')->toHtml(),
        'url'       => $this->getUrl('bulkpriceupdate/adminhtml_select/index', array('_current' => true)),
        'class'     => 'ajax'
    ));    

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

**Updated Question :**
i am trying to create a tab with grid.
when click this tab it continues loading with ajax loader an also displaying header like attached screenshot.

anyone already fixed the issue like this.,please suggest me why this header displaying.

Comment: i am trying to list products in this tab...but it shows header

Comment: how i can exactly get this...?????

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your layout file

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="header"/>
</reference>
```

After this save your changes. clear cache and check this.

Comment: i added this in my layout file,But it didnt work

Comment: @PriyaPonnusamy have you flush your cache?

Comment: @invissible yes i did ..

Comment: can you  please suggest that how to display form in one tab and grid in another tab